# What are the variables I need to know when using a cart?

Tags: php, loops, paypal, foreach, paypal-ipn

I am currently in the mood to develop my order system i have created for my game. This time I would like to add a cart system, so a user can purchase more than 1 item at a time!

I understand the variables to send to PayPal, but what I don't understand is the variables I am meant to be using when payment has been confirmed.

Right now, this is what I use to get the information PayPal sends

```
$p->ipn_data["item_name"];
```

But how will I get the whole cart details? Do I put a loop with an increment? 
EG:

```
$p->ipn_data["item_name_$i"];
```

$i would be the number of items selected, which i will try to find out.

Thanks if anyone could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out the entire array and see what you're getting.

```
$f = fopen("myipnlog.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($f, print_r($p->ipn_data, true) );
fclose($f)
```

Then write a loop to iterate over the data you expect to get (depending on the cart's contents)

Better yet, don't use IPN at all and switch to the Express Checkout API for the checkout.  Pass SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in the initial SetExpressCheckout API call if this is your only method of taking payment so that it will allow guest checkout.  More info here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec